# Web menus on Enterprise portal disabled

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I have a strange problem on one of Test environments. Web menus of type URL on a cutsom EP page are showing up as disabled. The user has admin access.
The same page on my dev system works fine.
Does anyone have a clue? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Atleast it works. There are two datasources on the page, unrelated. But if i make one of them as consumer using **Role="Consumer"**, the menu items are enabled. One of the menus has to be passed parameter from the datasources maybe that's why.